# Passing variable in window.open with self screen

Tags: javascript

I've following script in which I get the value of checked boxes & pass the information through window.open method. However `_self` is not working else it works fine in a new window. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#usethis').live('click', function(){
        var names = [];

        $('input:checked').each(function() {
            names.push($(this).val());
        });

        var name=names.join();
        var addresssame=1;
        window.open("xyz.php?names="+name+"&addresssame="+addresssame,"_self");
    });
});
```

Above code just refreshes the current page, however the above `window.open` code without `_self` works fine in other screen.
Can anyone tell what's getting wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do with "_self"? Function Window.open(url,windowName) will put "_self" as name of the new window for future references, but nothing else

Comment: I'm trying to open a page in a same window with _self, like a redirect. I mean once user clicks #usethis, it should open xyz.php page

Comment: Are you using Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Chrome is what I'm using

Comment: Why do you not use window.location = "newURL"; ?

Comment: That's not working either, this one window.location.href = "xyz.php?names="+name+"&addresssame="+addresssame;, it's not working still

Comment: what's the current URL? If it works in a new window but not in the current one, something in the current window is making it fail

Comment: Yeah you may be right @PabloLozano, I think I need to dig into some code, & find out what's failing it. I will get back to you

Comment: I'm thinking more in if the current URL is more or less the same (xyz.php with different parameters). Then it can be like using an anchor as a link: the page is not really re-loaded.

Comment: No the page is altogether different, to give you real names, it's checkout.php & the page I'm trying to load on a click event is payment.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a bug in the Mozilla documentation, but I could not find any reference to "_self" in the [window.open description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open).
Anyway, if you want to load anything in the current window, I recommend using:

```
window.location.href = "xyz.php?names="+name+"&addresssame="+addresssame;
```

instead calling `window.open`

Comment: Well I already tried to use this & surprisingly it's not working as well. I suspect any method is not working because of the each function I'm using or what.

Comment: Try to trace those values, add `console.log(names)`, for example

Comment: window.open("xyz.php?names="+name+"&addresssame="+addresssame); This one works absolutely fine with all proper values, only problem is it opens page in a different window.